# WPF Style to have a different color in the template when the ControlTemplate object is disabled

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

Say I have a style that looks like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                <Grid x:Name="Bg" Background="Grey">

                    <!-- Non-Relevant Stuff Here -->

                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And I want the grid background to be Red when the scrollbar is disabled.  I could do this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                <Grid x:Name="Bg" Background="Grey">

                    <!-- Non-Relevant Stuff Here -->

                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
          <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                   <Grid x:Name="Bg" Background="Red">

                       <!-- Non-Relevant Stuff Here -->

                   </Grid>
               </ControlTemplate>
           </Setter.Value>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

But that duplicates all of my template.  So now any changes have to be done in two places.

How can I get this trigger to allow me to change just the background of the grid in the template?

(Note: Adding a Setter for the Background property of the on the actual ScrollBar does not have any effect.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the `Trigger` in the `ControlTemplate` instead of the `Style`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                <Grid x:Name="Bg" Background="Grey">

                    <!-- Non-Relevant Stuff Here -->

                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                      <Setter TargetName="Bg" Property="Template" Value="Red"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to have your template reach out to obtain the value for the background from elsewhere, generally a property on the control. For example:

```
<Grid x:Name="Bg" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
```

Then your style trigger can simply change the `Background` property instead:

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
```

You will also likely want to set the default value for the background in your style. So you'll end up with something like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                <Grid x:Name="Bg" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">

                    <!-- Non-Relevant Stuff Here -->

                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```